# How to map array to a key in dictionary in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary with key as date & array of events.A date can have multiple events so i want to map one date as key of dictionary to the array of string.I will be dynamic a date can have no events or a date can have multiple events.I am getting data from array of dates i need to map it with events.

I have tried below code:

```
func addEventToDictionary(eventModal:CalenderEventModal,date:Date) {
    var key:String = self.dateFormatter().string(from: date)

    if let val = dict_events[key] {

    } else {
        dict_events[key]  = [Any]()
    }

    dict_events[key] = eventModal
}
```

Here Event modal is an Object of Event.

Comment: You tried this code, so what result you got and what did you expected?

Comment: let your dict_events = [String : [CalenderEventModal]] ?

Comment: `if let val = dict_events[key] { val.insert(eventModal)
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `dict_events` is a dictionary with a declared type of `[String: [Any]]`, then I believe all you're missing is appending to this array instead of assigning it. The value portion of the dictionary is Optional, so you need to append the value to a non-Optional array, then assign this back into your dictionary's `key`. Also, if you know you're only going to be storing `CalenderEventModal` objects, you could change the type of `dict_events` to `[String: [CalenderEventModal]]`. The fix for your code would look like this:

```
var dict_events: [String: [CalenderEventModal]] = [:]

func addEventToDictionary(eventModal: CalenderEventModal, date: Date) {
    var key: String = self.dateFormatter().string(from: date)

    if var val = dict_events[key] {
        val.append(eventModal)
        dict_events[key] = val
    } else {
        let events = [CalenderEventModal]()
        events.append(eventModal)
        dict_events[key] = events
    }
}
```

Comment: @KevinAleman You need to change the `[Any]()` to `[CalendarEventModal]()` and `dict_events` should be `var dict_events = [String: [CalenderEventModal]]()` - the is no need for the optional array; a dictionary either has an entry for a key or it doesn't

Comment: @dhiraj, what issues are you experiencing when using `append`? It's hard to debug your problems when we don't have the expected vs actual use cases of your code.

Comment: @Paulw11 you're correct; typos and brain farts on my end. :) Thanks for correcting me! I've edited my answer with the appropriate information.

Comment: @diraj, that's because the value portion of the dictionary is optional. I've edited my code with a solution that should work.